# How to split logs into three colums?

Tags: python

I have managed so far to read my Kubernetes pod logs into lines with Python

```
with open('2215.log','r') as f :
    for line in f.readlines():
             print (line)
```

Got this output

```
2023-08-24T12:19:00.536572476+01:00 stderr F Usage:

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536602997+01:00 stderr F    [flags]

2023-08-24T12:19:00.53661012+01:00 stderr F 

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536616965+01:00 stderr F Metrics server flags:

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536623251+01:00 stderr F 

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536631213+01:00 stderr F       --kubeconfig string            The path to the kubeconfig used to connect to the Kubernetes API server and the Kubelets (defaults to in-cluster config)

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536639663+01:00 stderr F       --metric-resolution duration   The resolution at which metrics-server will retain metrics, must set value at least 10s. (default 1m0s)

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536648184+01:00 stderr F       --version                      Show version

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536653981+01:00 stderr F 

2023-08-24T12:19:00.536660756+01:00 stderr F Kubelet client flags:
```

I want to separate them into

```
TIMESTAMP+'stderr F'+ the rest
```

How to do that?

Comment: Why not use tools like fluentbit to read pod logs and send to actual log analysis tools like Elasticsearch or Splunk?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am just practicing for Python test,but your ideas is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` takes a second argument to define the maxsplits, i.e.:

```
with open('2215.log','r') as f :
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line.split(' ', 2))
```

Will give you 2 splits (therefore give you 3 parts).  Note you have to explicitly define the separator too when using this.

Comment: This is going to split before the F

Comment: Exercise for the reader to fix that!